# Подключить JQWidgets в Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Установил JQWidgets в laravel через npm согласно инструкции на [оф.сайт](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/package-managers/npm-tutorial.htm)

```
npm install jqwidgets-scripts
```

Подключил пакет в файле bootstrap.js (*не знаю насколько это правильно*)

```
window.jqwidgets = require('jqwidgets-scripts');
```

Затем выполнил следующие команды

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

laravel mix собрал мне app.js

затем я в blade шаблоне подключаю виджет [tabs](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtabs/index.htm#demos/jqxtabs/defaultfunctionality.htm)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Create jqxTabs.
        $('#tabs').jqxTabs({ width: getWidth('tabs'), height: 250, position: 'top'});          
    });
</script>
```

и он ругается на этот кусок кода и говорит что нет функции **getWidth**
[image: консоль]

Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, виджеты подключились и работают, проблема была именно в функции getWidth. 
Так что топик можно закрывать.